# Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' to 'NSArray'

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code in my Share Extension in didSelectPost:

```
let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.appliaison.ActionExtensionSharingDefaults")
var urls: [String] = []
urls.append(self.contentText)
sharedDefaults?.setObject(urls, forKey: "stringKey")
```

and the following code in viewDidLoad in my main applications VC

```
var urls:[String] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.appliaison.ActionExtensionSharingDefaults")
        urls = (sharedDefaults?.objectForKey("stringKey") as? [String])!
   ...
    }
```

But when I run it, I get the following error :

> Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' to 'NSArray'

Comment: I suspect that at some point you saved into `NSUserDefaults` a `NSString` object for key @"stringKey", and not a `NSArray`. That seems to be your issue. Either you correct it by forcing a delete and come clean about it saving always a `NSArray` from now on, or you have to check if the object retrieved is a `NSArray` or a `NSString` and act accordingly to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 stringKey is as String in sharedDefaults.you can check with 
 following code

 if let item = sharedDefaults["stringKey"] {

     if item is String {

       print("I'm String -> \(item)")

    } else if item is [String] {

       print("I'm Arry -> \(item)")              
    }
}
```